# How to determine the supported thread model of an out-of-process COM server?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, com, out-of-process

**Question**:

- How to find the **threading models** supported by a predefined **out-of-process (EXE-based) Server**:
- Using [**oleview**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6)?
- Or any other valid methods?

**Note:**

- Attempting to connect to the above described server to receive event notifications

Comment: Check this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q150777/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the question is wrong.

Threading models (STA, MTA, etc) are a necessary evil that apply only to in-process COM objects, where objects and clients need to coexist in the same process and somehow they must prevent stepping on each other's toes (a fun and lengthy topic).

Out-of-process (EXE) COM servers live in their own process and manage their own threading as they see fit. COM doesn't know -- and doesn't care.

So there isn't any "threading model" (in a COM sense) associated with an EXE.

It sounds like you have a specific problem: If you post more details, I/someone/we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute **minimum** amount of registry entries for a class is:

- [**LocalServer32\**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683844(VS.85).aspx) (path to executable) - Location of local out-of-process EXE server
- **InprocServer32\** (path to DLL) - Location of local in-process DLL server

**Note:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\
{CLSID}\LocalServer32 = <full path>ServerExecutable
```